# How to solve Newton's method in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have to adapt Newton's implemantation for the  null solution of calculations 
following this function  $x = 1 - e^{-2x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Find a 0 for the function $f(x)=1-e^{-2x} - x$